# Create an associative array out of an array by using values that come from another array

Tags: php

I have several arrays.

```
$keysArray = ['Key1', 'Key2'];

$array1 = ['Value1', 'Value2'];

$array2 = ['Value1', 'Value2'];

$array3 = ['Value1', 'Value2'];
```

I want to make each array (except $keysArray) an associative array in which the keys would come from $keysArray.

So for instance, $array1 $array2 and $array3 would look like

```
['Key1' => 'Value1', 'Key2' => 'Value2'];
```

How can I efficiently achieve this?

Comment: Is the index from the keys and values always 1 on 1?

Comment: Yes, I'm basically taking data from a tab delimited text file and if a column is empty, it will still be part of the array, just empty value.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

```
array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )
```

So for your example:

```
$array1new = array_combine($keysArray, $array1);
```

Comment: Hi billy I edited my original post I had accidentally put a "key3" there.